# Changing the windows style?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, nonclient-area

How can I make my app look like the chrome window? With no title text and really slim border. Or like spotify with no border (or padding sortof).

Comment: How far did you get with your research? There are a [few screencasts on MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/uk/msdn/nuggets/nugget/21/Glass-with-C-in-Windows-Vista.aspx) That might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `FormBorderStyle` property of the form to `None`.